# Rotativa pdf bottom position is wrong after upgrade visual studio 17.8

Tags: pdf, visual-studio-2022, rotativa

After upgrade to visual studio version 17.8, there is somethings wrong in pdf bottom position as below

I'm currently using Rotativa.AspNetCore 1.3.2 with the below parameters

```
return new ViewAsPdf(view_name, model, view_data)
{
    PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A4,
    PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
    PageMargins = new Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Margins(2, 0, 5, 0),
    //PageMargins = { Left = 0, Right = 0 },
    //PageWidth = 180, // it's in millimeters
    //PageHeight = 277,
    CustomSwitches = "--disable-smart-shrinking",
    ContentDisposition = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.ContentDisposition.Inline
    //FileName = _doc_uri + fileName
    //SaveOnServerPath = _doc_
};
```

---

1.Visual studio 17.6

[image]

---

2. After upgrade to 17.8
   [image]

---

3. css for the bottom div element

```
#invoice_bottom {
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    height: 100px;
    width: 720px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
}

@media print {

     @page {
        size: A4 portrait; 
        margin: 0;
        
        @bottom-center {
          / *content: element(footer);*/
        }

        @top-center {
          /*content: element(header);*/
        }
    }

    html, body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I have no clue on this problem at all.
Could you please help

Comment: I see you have also posted this issue on Rotativa's Github page (https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore/issues/89) - if they can't fix it then you may need to start looking for alternatives.